# How can I get the file extension

Tags: mumps, intersystems-ensemble

In MUMPS how can I get the file extension is there a class I can use? Class(%File).GetFilename that will return the Full Message name but i would just like the extension?

Set tNameIn=##class(%File).GetFilename(pRequest.OriginalFilename)

Comment: Do you want standard Mumps or Cache Object Script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$piece](https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_fpiece) for this.

```
write $piece(tNameIn, ".", *)
```

Should return the latest piece delimited my symbol dot
And filename without extension will be

```
write $piece(tNameIn, ".", 1, *-1)
```